# Run gitlab-runner for several steps

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab runner to test my CI locally.

I run it with:

```
sudo gitlab-runner exec docker godep  --docker-privileged
```

Where godep is the job I need to run

Now, the next step is `gobuild`, but this step is dependant of the previous step, as it will generate an artifact

Is it possible to run several jobs with gitlab-runner ???

Answer (score 10):

One of the limitations of `gitlab-runner exec` is that it can only run one job, not full pipelines with all stages.

A full list of limitations can be seen [in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if I want to test my pipeline, I just run the entire pipeline using the configured runners.  This seems like it would be the easy solution instead of trying to duplicate it all manually.  You may get a couple failed pipelines on your Gitlab page, but that shouldn't be a show stopper.